# SOLVED What is the marginal pdf $f_1(x)$?

Tags: integration, statistics

$$f_1(x)=\int_0^2 (^2 + \frac13xy) dy$$
The answer was $2x^2 + 2x/3$ but I don't understand the steps to get that. Can someone explain step by step?

Comment: $\int x^2 dy=x^2y$ and $\int xy dy=\frac12xy^2$

Comment: thanks! I understand now, got confused with the xy part.

Comment: @Mary Maybe you could now post an answer yourself.